# Rename interface using Roslyn not working

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want to rename a class, its base class and the interface that it supports. For example I want to rewrite this:-

```
public class CustomerDAL : DALBase, ICustomerDAL
```

to this:-

```
public class CustomerRepository : RepositoryBase, ICustomerRepository
```

So I wrote this CSharpSyntaxRewriter:-

```
public class RenameBaseClassAndInterface : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    public override SyntaxNode VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        if (node.Identifier.Text.Contains("DAL"))
        {
            string className = node.Identifier.Text.Replace("DAL", "Repository");

            node = node.ReplaceToken(node.Identifier, SyntaxFactory.Identifier(className));

            if (node.BaseList != null && node.BaseList.Types != null)
            {
                foreach (BaseTypeSyntax baseTypeSyntax in node.BaseList.Types)
                {
                    TypeSyntax typeSyntax = baseTypeSyntax.Type;
                    IdentifierNameSyntax identifierNameSyntax = (IdentifierNameSyntax)typeSyntax;
                    if (identifierNameSyntax.Identifier.ToString() == "DALBase")
                    {
                        node = node.ReplaceToken(identifierNameSyntax.Identifier, SyntaxFactory.Identifier("RepositoryBase"));
                    }
                    else if (identifierNameSyntax.Identifier.ToString().Contains("DAL"))
                    {
                        string repositoryInterfaceName = identifierNameSyntax.Identifier.ToString().Replace("DAL", "Repository");
                        node = node.ReplaceToken(identifierNameSyntax.Identifier, SyntaxFactory.Identifier(repositoryInterfaceName));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return base.VisitClassDeclaration(node);
    }
}
```

What I actually get is this:-

```
public class CustomerRepository : RepositoryBase, ICustomerDAL
```

(i.e. ICustomerDAL does not get renamed to ICustomerRepository).

I can step through my code and I see that it reaches and executes the code to rename the interface and no error occurs, it just doesn't work. I suspect that this is because it is doing the rename on an old node and not the new node but I can't see what I have done wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have your foreach loop that is trying to update all of the tokens in the base list. Once you do the first call to ReplaceToken, you've created a new node that has new identity of tokens, so the second time you call you're ReplaceToken, you're passing in a token from the original node to the call that's happening on the new node. So the second call is probably returning the existing node rather than doing a replacement. (Unfortunately ReplaceToken is a no-op if it can't find the token, which is often confusing.)

Instead of your foreach loop as written, add the tokens that need replacing (or at least analysis) into a list, and then call [ReplaceTokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.syntaxnodeextensions.replacetokens?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.3.0). This takes a list of tokens to (potentially) replace, and a lambda that we'll call for each token to rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public override SyntaxNode VisitBaseList(BaseListSyntax node)
{
    if (node.Parent is ClassDeclarationSyntax cds && cds.Identifier.Text.Contains("DAL"))
    {
        BaseTypeSyntax baseType = SyntaxFactory.SimpleBaseType(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("RepositoryBase"));
        //...
        var repositoryTypeName = SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(repositoryInterfaceName);
        BaseTypeSyntax repositoryInterface = SyntaxFactory.SimpleBaseType(repositoryTypeName);
        return SyntaxFactory.BaseList().AddTypes(baseType, repositoryInterface).NormalizeWhitespace();
    }
    return base.VisitBaseList(node);
}
```